# Error in `[.data.frame`(m.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected when doing Mediation Analysis in R

Tags: r, statistics, analysis, mediator

I have the following dataset and I'm trying to run the mediate function on it:

```
> str(df)
tibble [33 × 7] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ BoroughName         : chr [1:33] "City of London" "Barking and Dagenham" "Barnet" "Bexley" ...
 $ BoroughPopulation   : num [1:33] 5.2 98.3 208.3 142.3 171.3 ...
 $ PM25PWACugm3        : num [1:33] 17.9 13.2 13.2 13 13.7 12.9 15.1 13.2 13.5 13 ...
 $ Baselinedeaths      : num [1:33] 40 1247 2353 1814 1477 ...
 $ Attributablefraction: num [1:33] 9.9 7.4 7.4 7.3 7.7 7.2 8.4 7.4 7.6 7.3 ...
 $ Attributabledeaths  : num [1:33] 4 92 174 132 112 182 91 173 142 138 ...
 $ Lifeyearslost       : num [1:33] 60 1268 2360 1772 1855 ...
```

I'm trying to run the mediate function with the following models for linear regression:

```
 # fit a linear regression model to predict PM2.5 PWAC from borough BoroughPopulation
 model1 <- lm(df$PM25PWACugm3 ~ df$BoroughPopulation)

 # fit a linear regression model to predict baseline deaths from PM2.5 PWAC
 model2 <- lm(df$Baselinedeaths ~ df$PM25PWACugm3)

 # fit a linear regression model to predict baseline deaths from borough BoroughPopulation and PM2.5 PWAC
 model3 <- lm(df$Baselinedeaths ~ df$BoroughPopulation + df$PM25PWACugm3)

 # install and load the 'mediation' package
 library(mediation)

 mediate_result <- mediate(model1, model2, model3, treat = "BoroughPopulation", mediator = "PM25PWACugm3", data = df)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(m.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected
```

I have checked the names of the columns multiple times and whether they contain any spaces or special characters, but they don't. The types of the variables also seem correct and I genuinely don't know what else could be the problem. Any help to make the mediate function work would be appreciated!

This is the dput(df) output:

> dput(df)
> structure(list(BoroughName = c("City of London", "Barking and Dagenham",
> "Barnet", "Bexley", "Brent", "Bromley", "Camden", "Croydon",
> "Ealing", "Enfield", "Greenwich", "Hackney", "Hammersmith and Fulham",
> "Haringey", "Harrow", "Havering", "Hillingdon", "Hounslow", "Islington",
> "Kensington and Chelsea", "Kingston upon Thames", "Lambeth",
> "Lewisham", "Merton", "Newham", "Redbridge", "Richmond upon Thames",
> "Southwark", "Sutton", "Tower Hamlets", "Waltham Forest", "Wandsworth",
> "Westminster"), BoroughPopulation = c(5.2, 98.3, 208.3, 142.3,
> 171.3, 199.8, 125.1, 212, 194, 177.3, 141.2, 126.1, 102.5, 142.9,
> 142.4, 150.1, 157, 143.3, 111.9, 101.5, 95.3, 165.4, 157, 119.9,
> 144.5, 157.6, 120.7, 157.7, 118.7, 118.6, 141.6, 173.4, 133.6
> ), PM25PWACugm3 = c(17.9, 13.2, 13.2, 13, 13.7, 12.9, 15.1, 13.2,
> 13.5, 13, 13.6, 14.5, 14.5, 13.7, 12.8, 12.6, 12.7, 13.4, 15.3,
> 15.1, 13.1, 14.4, 13.9, 13.5, 14, 13.3, 13.3, 14.9, 13.1, 15.5,
> 13.5, 14.1, 15.5), Baselinedeaths = c(40, 1247, 2353, 1814, 1477,
> 2524, 1085, 2349, 1867, 1897, 1584, 1015, 882, 1106, 1386, 2126,
> 1754, 1362, 1035, 803, 1000, 1360, 1552, 1143, 1221, 1716, 1131,
> 1338, 1391, 983, 1356, 1513, 1071), Attributablefraction = c(9.9,
> 7.4, 7.4, 7.3, 7.7, 7.2, 8.4, 7.4, 7.6, 7.3, 7.6, 8.1, 8.1, 7.7,
> 7.2, 7.1, 7.1, 7.5, 8.5, 8.4, 7.4, 8.1, 7.8, 7.6, 7.9, 7.4, 7.4,
> 8.3, 7.3, 8.7, 7.6, 7.9, 8.6), Attributabledeaths = c(4, 92,
> 174, 132, 112, 182, 91, 173, 142, 138, 120, 82, 71, 85, 100,
> 150, 125, 102, 88, 67, 74, 109, 120, 86, 96, 128, 84, 111, 102,
> 85, 102, 119, 92), Lifeyearslost = c(60, 1268, 2360, 1772, 1855,
> 2379, 1568, 2423, 2175, 1944, 1659, 1429, 1166, 1472, 1544, 1968,
> 1788, 1564, 1394, 1119, 1008, 1797, 1773, 1259, 1572, 1799, 1238,
> 1793, 1367, 1314, 1546, 1686, 1570)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("tbl_df",
> "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Can you provide `dput(df)` instead of `str(df)`?

Comment: Don't use the `df$` in front of the variable names and use `data=df` in the call to `lm()`.

Comment: @jrcalabrese - Yes, I edited the post to include this information.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Unfortunately, that didn't change anything

Comment: The `mediate()` function only works on two models, though that isn't the problem that's generating the error (not exactly at least).  The problem is that `mediate()` is looking for the treatment variable in the second model.  It looks like the way the code is written that you can't exclude the treatment variable from the outcome model (i.e., it must have both direct and indirect effects).  If you did `mediate_result <- mediate(model1, model3, treat = "BoroughPopulation", mediator = "PM25PWACugm3", data = df)` that would work.